# PHP Mail Server Spoof

Tags: php, email

How would I remove/change which server is displayed when an email is sent?

Currently, it is duffman.enixns.com; am I able to change this to my domain (viralaftermath.com)?

[image: Example]

Comment: If yuo have a domain, your host could provide you a smtp server for that. Otherwise, you have to keep doing it like you're doing and get that "via" notice in your email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be useful to add an SPF Record so that mail coming from your other domain ( duffman.enixns.com ) is treated as legitimate when it is set as from @viralaftermath.com

SPF records are held in your DNS records. Otherwise, this cannot be changed. I have noticed, however, that proper SPF records may lead Google to remove the "via" from the from address line, thus achieving your desired output.. That's only after the records have been there for a while and obviously at Google's discretion for Gmail only.